# How do we get the attention of question closers to re-open a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reopen-closed

The question ([c# NaN comparison differences between Equals() and ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933769/c-nan-comparison)) was one that I was about to answer, but it got closed as a duplicate before I had an opportunity.  I can see all the people who closed the question, but how can I get their attention to review their decision to close the question?  I think there would be a clear majority of the people who voted to close the question who would re-open the question if they read my comment, but is there anything leading them to do so?  There should be some way to send them a message either manually or automatically.

Comment: I just checked it out; [it wasn't close enough to be a dupe](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).  Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag the question.  When flagging the question, choose `other`, and include your reasons for wanting the post to be re-opened.

Moderators are special in that if you include our name in a comment using `@ModeratorName` (in my case, `@GeorgeStocker`) we'll get pinged. Think of it as our own bat-signal.

Please don't bring the question to meta unless there is a real need (by real need, I mean that you think that the attention outweighs the ire you'll draw for bringing it to meta instead of flagging it).

Comment: Flagging for moderator attention is the best way. It could take days before all who closed got notified.

Comment: "the ire you'll draw for bringing it to meta" - I'm saddened to learn that bringing questions to meta for reopen requests might elicit ire. I thought that was the recommended step, according to the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions): "If you're simply unsure about the validity of the closure, the best place to ask is on the community's meta site. "

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to get *their* attention, other people that come along can vote to reopen as well. The questions doesn't have to be reopened by the same people that closed it.

Comment: Well, I can't just flag down random people to re-open it.  If I'm going to get someone's attention, it makes the most sense to get the attention of the people who voted to close it.  I'm aware that anyone can vote to re-open it, but when it's closed, there aren't a whole lot of people looking at it any more so I feel we need a way to draw attention of specific people to the question.

Comment: Another reason for wanting to get the original close voters attention is to have a proper discussion about it. It's possible that if the original close voters saw the comments, they might alter their behaviour regarding future close votes.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: it actually makes least sense to get the attention of those who originally closed the question, because they're most motivated to keep it closed. Psychology 101 - humans have a need for consistency and not losing face.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a comment using @username for each user that closed the question to get the attention.

But if it is a duplicate and you have an answer, you can add it to the original (if it isn't given yet).

Comment: Problem is, it's not really a duplicate. That's why I think it should be re-opened.  Does @username do anything internal/special, or is it just a way to draw the attention of someone who is already looking at the comment anyway in case they're not paying attention?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: See to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work According to that, closers aren't on the list of valid targets for @ replies; only poster, commenters, and editors.

Comment: @Blue you can always find one of their answers and leave a temporary comment to get their attention.  I just did that to your account on SO.  Its a little goofy, but until some better solution comes...

Comment: Only one @mention is allowed, so you can't actually use "@username for each user". That would result in your [comment being blocked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).