# How to reopen a question by a third party

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

Today I have stumbled across a question that was closed .
When reading this question , I thought it was valid, and I even might have an answer for it .

So I went and read [THIS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) and [THIS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) along with some other related questions here on meta .

The issue is that because :

- I do NOT have 3000 points to vote for opening,
- The said question is not my own ,
- The person who closed it did not leave a comment,

  It seems that I have no option to reopen it and answer.

What one should do in that case ?

Flag it for moderator ?  I would think this is not the appropriate action here .

Contact the closer personally  ? - Same as Above (and also , how ?)

Leaving a simple comment ? By reading the above mentioned questions - leaving a simple comment will do nothing by itself to reopen or to catch attention (unless someone else stumbles upon it ..)

So what are my options for action ??

(the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182086/wordpress-change-image-name-during-uploading-sequentially) for reference)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Contact the closer personally ? - Same as Above (and also , how ?)

Just post a comment to the question using the '@username' format. Moderators are notified of such comments when they've closed a question - only moderators, don't go posting messages for regular users who voted to close a question, all you'll be doing is spamming the author of the question.

If you decide to post a comment, you can go two ways:

1. Ask why the question was closed, *or*
2. If you are certain the question should be re-opened, make a *good* case for it.

The question in question, however, is not a question that should be re-opened. The OP has found a very similar question and has made absolutely no effort to solve their problem on their own. Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying they should solve their problem on their own, but at least try and tell us about it.

> Flag it for moderator ? I would think this is not the appropriate action here .

Flagging for moderation attention would also be fine, that's what flags are for: Stuff you think should be done, but you can't do on your own.

Comment: But don't do anything now, you posted on Meta, moderators will see it...

Comment: Completely forgot about the "ping the closer personally" part of the question. That's another viable path.

Comment: Thanks - I indeed tried the @username , but it did not gave me the little popup with the option of the involved persons , so I thought that it will not work for the mod who closed it. also , in the other referenced answers - it clearly said that commenting will not help. and also - how to ping the closer personally ?

Comment: @krembo99 Mods are special cases (indeed we are!). Write the username by hand.

Comment: +1 for 1st half. I wasn't knowing this works.

Comment: Thanks - about this question - it was not really about the specific case of the question - but about a scenario that can re-occur. although i DO think that if a mod closes a question , he /she should leave a comment - especially if the user is clearly a totaly new one (1 point) and clearly do not know the "rules" . and returning to this specific question - I would think that the closer misread the question and thought it is about a simple "Interface" problem in wordpress - when in fact - it is a bout programming. so either way - the closing REASON was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Flagging is perfectly fine. In fact, most mods encourage a user to flag their closed question for reopening if it gets improved. (Eg [this comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/684/how-can-cornstarch-be-incorporated-into-a-metal#comment1143_684)). You may also bring it to meta (better to flag first).

Mods are human exception handlers, when something like this, a flag notifies them of the "exception" (in this case, an incorrectly closed question).

Note that you may be wrong about the "It is a valid question"--we don't just allow *any* types of questions. (We're not like those fora where anything goes).

In this specific case, I don't really understand what the OP is talking about, so I can't say much. If you think George Stocker was wrong in his decision to close, just flag the question and say "I feel that this post has been erroneously closed by George Stocker, could another mod review this?" (maybe add some more justification). I've read somewhere on meta that you can always specify if you do/don't want a certain mod to touch a flag--the mods will honor the request.

Comment: @Troyen: Thanks, didn't see. I'm not too clear about the topic or the question, so I can't comment on that particular close

Answer (score 3):

I closed it because it was flagged, and I agreed with the flag.  The flag was that it was off-topic, potentially that it belonged on the Wordpress Stack Exchange site.

I have a few issues with the question:

1. No code by the OP to show that they've tried something.
2. No discussion whether a plugin will solve their problem or whether they want to write code.
3. There's already a solution that the OP linked to, but *they couldn't be bothered to try to adapt that solution to their needs*.

Add that up and you have a few possible close reasons: Not A Real Question and Off Topic.

If the OP would like to put more effort into their question, I think it should be re-opened; but absent some work from the OP, it's not fair to the community to let those sorts of 'questions' slide.

As always, if you've got an issue with something I've done, please flag the post in question for moderator attention, and use 'other' as your flag reason. Explain your reasons, and another moderator will take a look at it.  It may not always be resolved to your liking, but it will always be resolved.

After re-reading the flag and re-reading the post; I've sent it over to the Wordpress.stackexchange.com site.

Answer (score 2):

Bringing to Meta is your best bet; or you can flag it and ask a moderator to re-open.

Source: [How do we get the attention of question closers to re-open a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78529/how-do-we-get-the-attention-of-question-closers-to-re-open-a-question)

Comment: No, let's not fill up Meta with pointless requests to re-open, please.

Comment: funny that the answer you linked was made by the same person who closed the question in my case . however - bringing this to meta every time on a case to case basis is not a solution IMHO, and - Like I said in my question, I would think that the flagging option is not for these cases .

Comment: @krembo99 Little detail though, George wasn't a moderator at the time.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Read the comments in order, dude, I'm replying to krembo99's comment that it was George who posted the Meta answer you link to and I'm just pointing out that he wasn't a moderator at the time (he posted the Meta answer).